# Locate multiple duplicate columns in PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql, subquery, duplication

I am trying to report on duplicate records in a single table which has a unique key of app_cao_number.  The duplicates occur if either: 1. The Passport field is duplicated; 2. The ID field is duplicated, or; 3. The Surname+FirstName are duplicated.

I can do this easily enough with three passes of the table using **ORDER BY**.  But I am hoping to use a single SELECT statement, with subqueries, to do the job.

Starting with just finding duplicate IDs I have the following statement:

```
SELECT app_cao_number, app_id,
    (SELECT app_id FROM people p2 
        WHERE p2.app_id IS NOT null 
        AND p2.app_id <> ''
        AND p1.app_cao_number <> p2.app_cao_number 
        AND p1.app_id = p2.app_id 
        GROUP BY p2.app_id) AS DupId
FROM people p1
WHERE app_id IS NOT null
AND app_id <> ''
```

This appears to get me the results that I want, but also include rows that have a null DupId - despite my attempts to ignore blank and null values in the SELECT statement.  Once this works I should be able to expand it to include the passport and name checks.

Please can someone explain why I have the following data output with nulls in the DupId column?  Thank you.

[image]

Further:
I thought it might be the **GROUP BY** clause, but I replaced it with a DISTINCT clause (below), but this gave the same result.

```
(SELECT DISTINCT p2.app_id FROM people p2 
    WHERE p2.app_id IS NOT null 
    AND p2.app_id <> ''
    AND p1.app_cao_number <> p2.app_cao_number 
    AND p1.app_id = p2.app_id 
    ) AS DupId
```

---

**UPDATE**

[sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=88294e065c2f95c1fe68bf415e5f90fd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for the model - does you need something like this?

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f529fa9e6bb73ca8544a6e2d3e9c5998)

> ```
> create table test (id int, value1 int, value2 int)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into test values
> (1,11,21),
> (2,12,22),
> (3,13,23),
> (4,14,24),
> (5,12,24),
> (6,16,26),
> (7,17,24),
> (8,18,28)
> ```
>
> ```
> 8 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select t1.id id, 
>        t2.id dup_id,
>        case when t1.value1 = t2.value1 then 'value 1'
>             when t1.value2 = t2.value2 then 'value 2'
>             else 'some error'
>             end dup_field,
>        case when t1.value1 = t2.value1 then t1.value1 :: text
>             when t1.value2 = t2.value2 then t1.value2 :: text
>             else 'some error'
>             end dup_value
> from test t1, test t2
> where t1.id < t2.id
> and ( t1.value1 = t2.value1
>       or
>       t1.value2 = t2.value2 )
> ```
>
> ```
> id | dup_id | dup_field | dup_value
> -: | -----: | :-------- | :--------
>  2 |      5 | value 1   | 12       
>  4 |      5 | value 2   | 24       
>  4 |      7 | value 2   | 24       
>  5 |      7 | value 2   | 24
> ```

Comment: Thanks Akina.  I see what you mean about fiddle now - I've never used/seen that before.  I'll try to use it in future.
I've tried your solution - but cut it down to simplify it - and it still produces a lot of columns that are empty.  Here is my code:


`select t1.app_id id, 
       t2.app_id dup_id,
       case when t1.app_id = t2.app_id then 'value 1'
            else 'some error'
            end dup_field
from sa_appl_contacts t1, sa_appl_contacts t2
where t1.app_cao_number < t2.app_cao_number
and ( t1.app_id = t2.app_id)`

Comment: @PaulPritchard Create a fiddle with YOUR sample data and add the link into your question text accompanied by desured result for that data. *Here is my code* If you need to search for duplicates in one field only then you do not need in CASE at all... *it still produces a lot of columns that are empty* Your code cannot give NULL in any field. While creating fiddle try to use example data which reproduces empty fields output for your query.

Comment: Hi @Akina, here is my fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=88294e065c2f95c1fe68bf415e5f90fd

This now produces 'twice' the result I'm looking for.  I haven't worried about the nulls here yet, I just want to get the output right.

Comment: on further looking at my example I see that it is adding a row for each duplicate now.  I just need a single row.

Comment: @PaulPritchard *here is my fiddle* It seems that you "want strange". Why you output `t1.passport ppt, t2.passport dup_ppt` when you set that `t1.passport = t2.passport` in WHERE??? They're always equal... *This now produces 'twice' the result I'm looking for.* Be more precise - WHAT value in WHAT field do you tell about?

Comment: you are correct - the reason I put in t2.passport is just so that I am sure it really is working.
I've now added a DISTINCT into my SELECT statement which now just gives me the three rows I am looking for: those uniquekey values that are duplicated elsewhere.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a7b4cef87f082063673bb7a22ace1b03

Let me look at adding in some nulls and blank records and then extending it to capture duplicate IDs.

Comment: I think that I have cracked the Id and Passport checks with your help: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b894f7db06abdad66a94ebc61890e12c

It should be straight forward(ish) now to extend this to include the surname+firstname.

Answer (score 0):

If the subquery in the `SELECT` list returns no result, you will get a NULL value. You seem to expect that that would result in that result row from being excluded, but that is not the case.

What about a simple query like

```
SELECT app_id, count(app_cao_number)
FROM people
GROUP BY app_id HAVING count(app_cao_number) > 1;
```

Comment: Hi again @Laurenz.  You helped me before recently.  This is such a simple, elegant answer and works perfectly for the duplicate app_id problem.  Thank you.

However.  Extending this to find duplicates in the password column doesn't look very easy.  I've searched for multiple GROUP BY clauses and found nothing.
But at least doing three passes over the data using this command will be very quick.